# TypeError when trying to send a DM to a mentioned user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a remind command in discord.js which takes two arguments: the message and the mentioned user that should be reminded. However, it's giving me an error.

Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 const { content, guild, channel, author } = message;
 if (!guild) return;
 if (author.bot) return;

 const args = content
  .slice(process.env.PREFIX.length)
  .trim()
  .split(/ +/g);
 const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (cmd == 'remind') {
  const remindeduser = message.mentions.users.first().id;
  const msg = message.toString();
  remindeduser.send(msg.slice(8));
 }
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
/home/runner/ServerParty/index.js:82
      remindeduser.send(msg.slice(8));
                   ^

TypeError: remindeduser.send is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ServerParty/index.js:82:20)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/ServerParty/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This link is asking me to sign up for a website. Please post your actual code. Also, please provide the error you got.

Comment: when it asks you to sign up for repl.it you create an acc,and it redirects but ill paste on hatebin then and ill add the errors

Comment: Please just paste the relevant code directly instead of linking a third party service.

Comment: I have @Lioness100

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to include the errors directly into the post, instead of linking to an external site. I've also removed some of the unnecessary code that you have included — always include a [mcve] and not your entire code. I've also improved your title so that it's clearer as to what you are asking. The reason why you were downvoted is likely because the question shows no effort to solve the problem (which is relatively simple to fix), and the problem is very specific to your code and is unlikely to help others. Please see the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are in these three lines:

```js
const remindeduser = message.mentions.users.first().id;
const msg = message.toString();
remindeduser.send(msg.slice(8));
```

---

First of all, You can't call the [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) function on a `User Snowflake (ID)`

```js
// change:
message.mentions.users.first().id;

// to:
message.mentions.users.first();
```

Also, to handle possible errors, add these lines:

```js
const remindeduser = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!remindeduser)
 return message.channel.send('Please mention a user to remind');
const msg = message.toString();
remindeduser
 .send(msg.slice(8))
 .catch(() => message.channel.send('Cannot DM this user'));
```

---

Secondly, `message.toString()` is not a function. The [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) parameter returns an `object` with all data of the message. For example, `message.author`, `message.guild`, `message.id`, etc.

To get the actual text within the message, use [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content), which you have already defined as just `content`.

```js
const msg = content.toString();
remindeduser.send(msg.slice(8));
```

Also, there actually isn't any use for that line. You already have the `args` variable.

```js
// replace:
const msg = content.toString();
remindeduser.send(msg.slice(8))

// with:
remindeduser.send(args.join(' '))
```